# Spectal plotting within Python?

Tags: python, plot, astronomy, astropy

Is there a way to plot spectra in python such that it has square levels (histogram 'like'; therefore the spectral resolution is taken into account), rather than a continuous line which simply connects the points?

Comment: Python is very powerful and can do almost anything, can you be more specific?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] then edit your question to include whatever code you have tried. SO isn't a code writing service - if you want to buy code there are plenty of providers out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matplotlib, which is the most commonly used package for plotting spectra, you can use the `drawstyle='steps-mid'` option.  See http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot for details.

This question is asked and answered in detail here:
http://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2012/01/27/pretty-plotting-of-spectra-ask-astrobetter/